# In Concurrency in C# there is a 'MouseEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'GetPosition'

Tags: c#, winforms, system.reactive

I am reading the book "Concurrency in C# Cookbook" by Stephen Cleary and on the chapter dealing with Rx Recipe 5.2 sending notifications to a context there is a case where we need to do a CPU-intensive computation whenever the mouse moves.

So we have the following sample code:

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var uiContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

            Trace.WriteLine("UI Thread is " + Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId);
            Observable.FromEventPattern<MouseEventHandler, MouseEventArgs>(
                handler => (s, a) => handler(s, a),
                handler => MouseMove += handler,
                handler => MouseMove -= handler)
                .Select(evt => evt.EventArgs.GetPosition(this))
                .ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default)
                .Select(position =>
                {
                    //Complex Calculation
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    var result = position.X + position.Y;
                    Trace.WriteLine("Calculated Result " + result + " on thread " +
                        Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId);
                    return result;
                }
                )
                .ObserveOn(uiContext)
                .Subscribe(x => textBox1.Text = "Result " + x + "on Thread " + Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId
                );
        }
```

However the code does not compile because:
'MouseEventArgs' does not contain a definition of GetPosition and no extension method GetPosition accepting a first argument of type  MouseEventArgs could be found'

Am I missing something here?

EDIT: Investigating more I see in the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.mouseeventargs?view=netframework-4.6.1) that MouseEventArgs *does have* a GetPosition function but this MouseEventArgs is defined in the System.Windows.Input namespace while the one in my code is on System.Windows.Forms  I wonder if that is the problem

EDIT2: Investigating furthermore I found a [different documentation!](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs?view=netframework-4.7.2) in which MouseEventArgs does not have a GetPosition!

Now I tried to use the System.Windows.Input one in the code but my IDE says that this namespace does not have a MouseEventArgs contradicting the first doc.

Comment: I know you already got the answer, but there is a MVVM framework [ReactiveUI](https://reactiveui.net/), which also has a package specific for WInforms with all events already generated for you, so you can just write thigns like: `MyTextBox.Events().TextChanged.Subscribe(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.Windows.Input` namespace is for `WPF` applications so you should stick with `System.Windows.Forms`. `MouseEventArgs` contains `Location` property which contains mouse coordinates relative to control which fired an event. I think it is an equivalent to `GetPosition`.